# Why aren't bounced 'normal' emails reported?

Tags: civimail, bounce

You can configure CiviCRM to handle bounced emails.  Any mail to an invalid address seems to cause the mail to appear in the bounced email mailbox.  The Fetch Bounces job fetches them and deletes them, but it seems the Bounces Report only shows those from Bulk Emails.  Why is this?  Surely, *all* email bounces should be reported?

Answer (score 1):

Fuzion has undertaken some work recently to address this. The work is still underway but we expect to publish as an extension when this is completed.